# Error whilst performing gCentroid in R

Tags: r, polygon, centroid, rgeo-shapefile

I am unable to get centroids from polygons in R. The confusing bit is, it used to work in the past and has suddenly stopped working! This is the piece of code:

```
polygon.centroids <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(gCentroid(polygon, byid = TRUE), 
                                      polygon@data, match.ID = FALSE)
```

I can also confirm that the proj4string for the polygon data already exists and is as follows:

```
proj4string:    +proj=utm +zone=55 +south +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs
```

The error message that I am getting upon executing the centroids code is as follows:

> ```
>    Error in TopologyFunc(spgeom, id, byid, "rgeos_getcentroid") : 
>   no slot of name "proj4string" for this object of class "sf"
> ```

Any idea what's going on? As mentioned earlier, this code HAS WORKED OKAY in the past.

Thanks

Comment: You appear to be mixing `sf` objects with `sp` objects. what is the output of `class(polygon)` ? Perhaps you're after the `st_centroid(polygon)` function from `library(sf)`  ?

Comment: @SymbolixAU- Thanks for your response. I checked and it is an sf object and st_centroid seems to work. However, I have further processing to do in which I have to perform an intersect with an sp object. How do I go about converting sp to sf or vice versa whichever is easier? Thanks once again.

Comment: use `sf::st_as_sf` to go from `sp` to `sf`

Comment: Hi @SymbolixAU- sp to sf does not work for me unfortunately. It returns an error: invalid crs: +init=epsg:28355 +proj=utm +zone=55 +south +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs, reason: no system list, errno: 22.

This occurs even if I assign the proj4string.

Comment: Could be something to do with a broken `rgdal` installation. I'm just guessing though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`as()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/methods/versions/3.4.3/topics/as) function from the [`methods`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/methods/versions/3.4.3) package to convert your `sf` object to a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` object - as mentioned in [Reading, Writing and Converting Simple Features](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sf/vignettes/sf2.html).

Here, I use polygons from the [City of Chicago's 77 community areas](https://data.cityofchicago.org/Facilities-Geographic-Boundaries/Boundaries-Community-Areas-current-/cauq-8yn6) to reproduce this suggestion.

**Update**

Rather than transforming your entire `sf` object for the sole purpose of calculating centroids, you can do the conversion inside of [`gCentroid()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rgeos/versions/0.3-26/topics/gCentroid).

```
# load neccessary packages
library( sf )
library( rgeos )

# load data
comarea606 <-
    read_sf( "https://data.cityofchicago.org/api/geospatial/cauq-8yn6?method=export&format=GeoJSON" )

# find the centroid of each polygon
gCentroid( spgeom = comarea606 )
# Error in TopologyFunc(spgeom, id, byid, "rgeos_getcentroid") : 
#     no slot of name "proj4string" for this object of class "sf"

# convert from sf
# to spatial polygon data frame
# to find the centroid of each polygon
centroids <- 
    gCentroid( 
        spgeom = methods::as( object = comarea606, Class = "Spatial" )
        , byid = TRUE 
        )

# view results
centroids
# SpatialPoints:
#     x        y
# 1  -87.61868 41.83512
# 2  -87.60322 41.82375
# 3  -87.63242 41.80909
# 4  -87.61786 41.81295
# 5  -87.59618 41.80892
# 6  -87.68752 41.97517
# 7  -87.61793 41.79236
# 8  -87.59231 41.79409
# 9  -87.59493 41.77888
# 10 -87.67017 42.00962
# 11 -87.77117 41.97883
# 12 -87.75836 41.99393
# 13 -87.72358 41.98364
# 14 -87.72156 41.96807
# 15 -87.76340 41.95403
# 16 -87.72345 41.95358
# 17 -87.80602 41.94651
# 18 -87.79803 41.92930
# 19 -87.76550 41.92726
# 20 -87.69501 42.00157
# 21 -87.73474 41.92435
# 22 -87.71121 41.93867
# 23 -87.69916 41.92276
# 24 -87.72092 41.90007
# 25 -87.67636 41.90121
# 26 -87.76311 41.89410
# 27 -87.73023 41.87859
# 28 -87.70590 41.87891
# 29 -87.66352 41.87401
# 30 -87.71722 41.86019
# 31 -87.65588 41.96581
# 32 -87.71400 41.83909
# 33 -87.66757 41.85027
# 34 -87.62033 41.85718
# 35 -87.63397 41.84208
# 36 -87.80345 41.98524
# 37 -87.63331 41.89960
# 38 -87.62519 41.87887
# 39 -87.57278 41.76158
# 40 -87.61597 41.74021
# 41 -87.58635 41.74420
# 42 -87.55143 41.74124
# 43 -87.59648 41.72818
# 44 -87.57272 41.72968
# 45 -87.62337 41.70659
# 46 -87.68384 41.94779
# 47 -87.59825 41.70613
# 48 -87.57006 41.69064
# 49 -87.53490 41.70731
# 50 -87.63574 41.67382
# 51 -87.60285 41.66014
# 52 -87.54658 41.66053
# 53 -87.76424 41.79619
# 54 -87.72636 41.81088
# 55 -87.69886 41.81737
# 56 -87.67250 41.82992
# 57 -87.65600 41.94423
# 58 -87.64879 41.83615
# 59 -87.65917 41.80902
# 60 -87.72421 41.79298
# 61 -87.69644 41.79543
# 62 -87.76851 41.77958
# 63 -87.72693 41.76978
# 64 -87.69567 41.77185
# 65 -87.66660 41.77593
# 66 -87.64250 41.77720
# 67 -87.61613 41.76325
# 68 -87.64949 41.92269
# 69 -87.70837 41.74576
# 70 -87.65631 41.74421
# 71 -87.67508 41.71315
# 72 -87.64890 41.71749
# 73 -87.71319 41.69488
# 74 -87.66905 41.68973
# 75 -87.89370 41.97568
# 76 -87.66342 41.98671
# 77 -87.81378 42.00761
# Coordinate Reference System (CRS) arguments: +proj=longlat
# +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 

# end of script #
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Convert from sf to sp code does not seem to work. Returns the following error: Error in methods::as(object = union.centroids, class = "Spatial") : 
  unused argument (class = "Spatial").

Comment: Try changing it to `methods::as(object = union.centroids, Class = "Spatial") `and see how it works.

Comment: Your code is of course correct, so +1. However, I would recommend converting from `sp` to `sf` as the latter has now superseded the former.

Comment: @SymbolixAU thank you for your advice. I will take your word for this as good practice. I'm in the land of `sp` and importing shape files using `rgdal` but am trying to force myself to learn and use `sf` more.